# Reading voltage across Christmas light wires, multimeter shows erratic readings

Tags: low-voltage, voltmeter

I am attempting to splice a simple on/off switch into a strand of Christmas lights.

Previously, I separated the two wires and cut open the one marked with dots, expecting it to be the positive/live lead. I joined the two leads of the switch to the two open ends of the dotted wire.

Testing, the lights appeared to work as expected: leaving them connected to power through their transformer and toggling the switch toggled the lights successfully.

However, later I noticed that with the switch set to off, the lights appear very dimly lit.

Googling around, I discovered that:

1. This can happen if the switch is installed on the neutral side of the circuit, and
2. While the standard marking is dotting the live wire, sometimes the opposite is true.

So I cut everything apart, and measured the two open ends of the wires coming out of the power supply with my multimeter in voltage mode, direct current, to determine polarity.

However, when doing so my multimeter readings do not stabilize, instead oscillating randomly between 10 and -10 volts at the refresh rate of the multimeter screen.

The power supply is marked as providing 36V DC.

Here is a picture, with the two open leads I tested (when the thing was plugged in), and with the power supply markings hopefully visible.

[image: power supply]

Here is a drawing, hopefully illustrating the situations:

[image]

What is happening here?

How do I wire the switch so that the lights are completely off when the switch is in the off position?

Comment: Is the switch on the AC or DC side? Please clarify with a schematic or block diagram of what you are measuring between and where the switch is.

Comment: The switch is on the DC side, between the transformer and the lights. I'll do my best to provide a drawing.

Comment: Some of my disassembled Christmas lights are 34 V DC BUT has an H-bridge on the output to drive two discrete strings of LEDs in order to save one wire in the harness and add some “feature” of blinking sections. Does it have a button to switch between modes?

Comment: Yes, it can switch between modes. I never noticed that the lights weren't synchronized, but testing with an identical and unmodified device there appear to be two or three different led groups.

Comment: Looks like the output of PS is not DC but unipolar pulses, after diode bridge.

Comment: please do a safety check before you do anything else ... measure the voltage between the bare wire and the power outlet earth ground ... the bare wire may be at full powerline voltage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a simple power supply. And even if it was, the LEDs could still be slightly light up.

The problem is not seen in your schematics because what matters is how you installed the LEDs and where, with how long wiring and mounted where.

If the LED wiring has capacitive coupling to earth ground, then any capacitive mains leakage from LED driver will pump some current through LEDs.

That is likely a 2-prong power supply internally and they have an Y cap between mains and low voltage side for preventing electromagnetic interference but then it will cause this leakage.

And LEDs are very sensitive and light up with very little leakage current.

If you can, try swappint the polarity how you plug the power supply to mains, but it looks like you have polarized plugs so it might not work.

Also what is the white device on the black power supply, it can make the problem worse.

One solution is to use a dual pole switch to isolate both wires going to LED driver, not only one.

Comment: The white device in the picture is a passive adaptor to connect the German (schuko) standard plug to my Italian socket. Both standards have two progs for AC current and a third connector for ground.  I don't have a dual pole switch, unfortunately.

Comment: The led strip is attached to the wall, far from mains lines, with a 3m wire. The led chain itself is 5m long, and counts about 100 LEDs.

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando Yes but does the LED supply even have and use a ground prong?

Comment: Ah, you're right. It has the grooves where the ground connectors would be, but no actual connector.

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando So if you measure with AC setting the voltage from LED+ or LED- output wires to earth ground prong, when supply is running, what do you get? Also if you touched the LED+ or LED- output wires, did you feel any tingly or vibrating sensation from leakage current?

Answer (score 0):

If you have modes on it and the string comes in groups despite only two wires from your power supply, the powersupply is followed by an H-bridge, controlled by an MCU. One group runs off positive polarity and the other runs off negative. Both are relying on the reverse voltage withstand of the LEDs.

Mine runs at 100 Hz, with square wave output, this is enough to leak capacitively across your switch to see the LEDs glow faintly despite switched off.

What you can do to mitigate it is to switch both wires with a two-pole switch, which should allow about half of the current to bleed across it.

If not enough, find a switch which happens to give higher separation distance between the contacts as capacitance will drop exponentially with distance.

If you can’t find one, an LC-filter, probably modded into the switch itself should decrease the rise time and give less capacitive coupling.

Also, try to set it in a mode which dims slowly between the two groups.

Here is a simulation for you. Your switch is SW1 in open position and C1 is the parasitic capacitance across the switch. Actual capacitance of it as well as the rise-time of the H-bridge are guesses, but the principle is the same, high frequencies goes though your parasitic capacitor. If you have any piece of audio equipment, you can sometimes hear that if you switch a channel off with a switch, the audio gets *almost* muted except for high frequencies. Same phenomenon.

[image]

The RMS current is about 1000 less than in normal operation, but enough to make them glow faitly.